# which c++ stl data structure will be the most efficient for storing unique values and their counts?

Tags: c++, performance, data-structures, std

I have a list of values, with some recurrences, e.g. : {1,2,2,3,3,3,3,7,8,1}

I want to store the unique values in this list in a data structure along with their counts.

```
    --------------
    |value |count|
    --------------
    |  1   |  2  |
    --------------
    |  2   |  2  |
    --------------
    |  3   |  4  |
    --------------
    |  7   |  1  | 
    --------------
    |  8   |  1  |
    --------------
```

which c++ standard library data structure will be the most efficient in doing so?

edit: i wont be modifying the structure in any way, i  just want to know the count as the count will help me determine the output to a programming question.

Comment: A vector of pairs, or a pair of vectors, depending on your most common access pattern. But generally either would be OK.

Comment: A `std::map` or a `std::unordered_map` could be used to

Comment: *which c++ stl data structure will be the most efficient in doing so* -- You only listed 10 numbers.  In your real application, how many unique numbers are you expected to have?  A thousand?  A million?

Comment: what is the most efficient depends on what operations you intend to use on the data structure. Different containers make different tradeoffs between insertion / lookup / removal / etc. Please clarify what you mean with "efficient"

Comment: @Damien Both of these structures are much less efficient. Unless you need the added functionality they provide, don’t use them.

Comment: @KonradRudolph It is difficult to discuss about efficiency if we don't know how this structure will be used. For example, a `std::map` is often used as a simple way to get the count of each value: `m[x[i]]++; `.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First note that asking for "the most efficient" data structure is not a proper characterization of your requirements. Do you want a solution which:

- is the fastest to use? In what use cases?
- takes up the least amount of memory?
- is the most maintainable/readable?
- is the least bug-prone?
- is the fastest to write?
- exists alongside the original data structure (for the uncounted values), or in its stead?

You see, there are different kinds and aspects to efficiency.

Having said that, you could try:

- A simple and straightforward solution was suggested to you by @songyuanyao and @RahulGupta: Use a map - an `std::map` if you want to interate your value-counts in increasing order, or an `std::unordered_map` if you don't care about the order. This will be easy to write and maintain, and kind-of-ok in terms of the time of inserting or removing an element. Still, both of these map structures are [quite slow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42588384/1593077), so you might rethink whether you even want a standard-library map implementation.
- An alternative solution - which is more efficient in terms of space and time if you perform a lot of reads and few inserts/updates - is what @KonradRudolph suggested in a comment: `std::pair<std::vector<value_type>, std::vector<count_type>>` or `std::vector<std::pair<value_type, count_type>>`; and make sure the `count_type` is large enough that you don't exceed it, but as small as it can be to reduce the amount of time you need for reading the whole structure. These will use a *lot* less space than the maps, since there are no bucket-lists, no empty

  Note that the choice between a vector-of-pairs or a pair-of-vectors is a common dilemma in data structure design, and is also known as "structure of arrays vs array of structs", or SoA vs AoS. See a [concrete example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17924705/structure-of-arrays-vs-array-of-structures-in-cuda) here on the site and there are many others. AoS is better when you usually access both fields, and need the corresponding values together; SoA is better when you often need just one field (e.g. you want to sum up the counts between some range of values; or you want to obtain the set of all prime values etc.) This also relates to the architecture of databases - [row-oriented vs column-oriented](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Column-oriented_DBMS), with the former being more appropriate for transaction processing and the latter for analytic workloads.

Comment: @ThePhobiCeron: "Thank you" messages are redundant on StackOverflow - the way we express this sentiment is by upvoting, and by accepting if the answer resolves the problem. Nothing more is necessary... (PS - I know that there's now a "thanks" widget, but this is [an unpopular experiment](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/398367/1593077) which will hopefully go away.)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a map in c++
declaration can be done as

```
map<int,int>map_name;
```

for inserting you can run a loop

```
for(auto itr:list_name)
    map_name[itr]++;

for(auto c:map_name)
cout << c.first << " " << c.second << endl;
```

Comment: `itr` is a bad name, because it suggests it would be an iterator, but it isnt.